# Does a pipeline stall occur on an ARM to Thumb switch?

Tags: arm, pipeline, thumb

In ARM architecture, if an ARM to Thumb mode switch occurs, will a pipeline stall occur?
If so, how many cycles are affected?
Is this same for Thumb to ARM mode switching ?
Does this behavior vary with different ARM processors ?

Comment: You should probably specify the specific architecture.  For *thumb-1*, the difference was only in the decoding logic.  Basically, the thumb op-codes map directly to ARM op-codes.  So, thumb mode is mostly like a de-compressor stream at the front of the pipeline.  If a stall occurs, it will be similar to a branch.  For instance, I don't believe the Cortex-A can predict a `bx` and certainly not a `movs pc, lr`.  It may also depend on **how** you switch modes.  A `msr CPSR,Rn` is probably different than `bx lr`.

Comment: @artlessnoise the instruction set bits are ignored on writes to `CPSR` anyway (outside of debug state).

Comment: What happened when you tried it and timed it?

Comment: @Notlikethat  Fair enough; I didn't really mean the specific instruction.  A mode switch (and context switch) between ARM/Thumb will be different from *inter-working* switches between ARM/Thumb (like `bx lr`).  So, a Linux Thumb User space switch to Linux ARM kernel space will be different from a mixed code thumb/ARM user-space executable which switches based on function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you switch in the sensible way (with `BLX`/`BX LR`), [any](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0488e/way1382448710808.html) [modern](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0500d/CHDIBCFC.html) [core](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0438c/BABCBGJI.html) [will](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0464d/CHDIBCFC.html) [predict](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0388g/CHDIBCFC.html) [that](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344c/Cacichgi.html) (assuming the branch predictor isn't turned off, of course). Writing to the `PC` directly is a little more variable - generally, big cores might predict it but little cores won't - but is generally best avoided anyway.

Otherwise an interworking branch is AFAIK no different to a regular branch, so if it isn't predicted the penalty is just a pipeline flush. The only other way to switch instruction sets is via an exception return, which is a synchronising operation for the whole core (i.e. not the place to be worrying about performance).

Comment: Writing an odd number into PC might lead to some unpleasant consequences instead of switching to thumb.

Comment: True, particularly on older architectures. From v7, nearly all writes to the PC are interworking, but it's still recommended to avoid writing to the PC directly except for the documented cases which are recognised as return instructions.

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all.

The cost is just like any other branch instruction. If the predictor hits, it's free, if not, it costs the usual 13 cycles.

There's no additional hidden hiccups due to the switching.

Therefore, you can use the interworking mode without worrying about potential penalties related to the mode switching.

Comment: This is true for most modern ARM CPUs.  If you post to [tag:embedded], people will insist that ARM7TDMI is very common and quote [Wikipedia's ARM7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM7) page (that is a CPU and not an arch version).  Before ARMv5 (the arch version), the thumb *inter-working* was more painful and I think the answer will be different.