# Performance cost of switching between arm and thumb mode?

Tags: embedded, cross-compiling, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture

Beside latency costs and registers can get reallocated. What are the other source of execution overheads of switching from arm to thumb mode and vice versa during execution that would affect performance?

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0203f/Bcghfebi.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780301/does-a-pipeline-stall-occur-on-an-arm-to-thumb-switch